# How to project 3D vector on unit sphere to 2D in $xz$ plane?

Tags: trigonometry, projective-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, python

I'm trying to use Python to do something that I thought would be simple geometry, but I don't understand the math behind what I'm computing.

I want to project a 3D vector on the unit sphere to 2D on the xz plane, and then compute the 2D projected angle of the projected vector on the xz plane (say, relative to the z-axis). I already know the spherical angles $\theta$ (the 3D polar angle relative to z-axis) and $\phi$ (the 3D azimuthal angle, relative to the x-axis for the 3D vector projected onto the xy plane).

I was told that the 2D projected angle $\psi$ (in the xz plane, relative to the z-axis) can be computed via

tan($\psi$) = tan($\theta$)cos($\phi$)

but it's not obvious to me how to derive that. How do I verify that formula?

Comment: Is what you're looking for the angle that the projected vector makes with the $z$ axis?

Comment: @user438666 yes exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your point has coordinates $(x,y,z) = (r \sin\theta \cos \phi, r \sin \theta \sin \phi, r \cos \theta)$. Then, $$\tan \psi = \frac{x}{z} = \frac{r \sin \theta \cos \phi}{r \cos \theta} = \tan \theta \cos \phi$$

Comment: Wow, amazing, I can't believe I didn't think of this! Thanks so much!

Comment: Wait, but what gave you the insight in the first place to do tan(psi) = x/z? (without going to my answer up top)? Is it because tan(psi) = x/z already takes into account the 3D x and z components projected onto the xz plane?

Comment: @quantumflash Orthogonal projection onto the $x$-$z$ plane simply sets $y$ to zero.

Comment: @amd thanks! so that implies that the only possible trigonometric function is tan(psi) = x/z because the other two, sin and cos, would involve y?

Comment: @quantumflash No. Once you’ve eliminated the $y$ coordinate, you’re just working in two dimensions, with the $z$- and $x$-axes playing the roles of the 2-D $X$- and $Y$-axes, respectively.

Comment: @amd Ah ok thanks so much! And one last question -- why does the 3D z axis become the 2D analog of the X-axis, and the 3D x-axis become the 2D analog of the Y-axis, and not the other way around?

Comment: @quantumflash Picture it in your head or draw it out. If you take them in the other order you get a left-handed coordinate system.

Comment: @quantumflash It looks like amd explained it well, but here's my intuitive explanation. You are interested in the $xz$ plane specifically, so I drew a copy of the $xz$ plane. The coordinates in that plane are exactly $(x,z) = (r \sin \theta \cos \phi, r \cos \theta)$ because we are projecting orthogonally to the plane. Then, we measure the angle $\psi$ from the $z$ axis, so the opposite side is the $x$-coordinate, and the adjacent side is the $z$-coordinate. That's why $\tan \psi = \frac{x}{z}$.

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you!